# Why $\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}dx=4$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I did the following calculations: $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}dx=\int_{-1}^{1}|x|^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx=\int_{-1}^0(-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx+\int_{0}^1x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx=\frac{(-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2}}\Biggr|_{-1}^0+\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2}}\Biggr|_{0}^1=-2\sqrt{1}+2\sqrt{1}$$

Comment: So, where are you getting 4?

Comment: That's the solution of my textbook

Comment: If you want to do the $\int_{-1}^0$ part separately, you need to substitute $u=-x$ before using the power rule. This supplies a negation that you've missed here.

Comment: Note that when you differentiate $(-x)^n$ you get $-n(-x)^{n-1}$, not $n(-x)^{n-1}$. This has implications for the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the integral between zero and 1 and multiply by two, the integral in the negative region has the same value as the positive region.

In your calc you have to divide by the differential of $-x$ in the negative region, which is $-1$ thus giving a double negative

Answer (score 4):

That's because, as the integrand is an even function,
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}\,\mathrm dx=2\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm dx = 4\sqrt x\biggm|_0^1.$$